# How to deploy .sekrets.key to heroku when I don't check it in Git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I use [Sekrets](https://github.com/ahoward/sekrets) gem to securely manage SendGrid credential and other sensitive keys. The credential is encrypted in **config/sekrets.yml.enc**, and to decrypt, **.sekrets.key** file is needed, but it's not added in the git repo.

I'm curious how to deploy the **.sekrets.key** to heroku so that keys in **config/sekrets.yml.enc** can be read.

Below are the errors when I deploy my learning Rails project to heroku.

> `$ git push heroku master`

```
...
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        missing /tmp/build_671f2f0c0250a9bd91df5c10138a4aae/.sekrets.key
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `sendgrid' for "{}\n":Map
remote:        /tmp/build_671f2f0c0250a9bd91df5c10138a4aae/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/map-6.6.0/lib/map.rb:652:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_671f2f0c0250a9bd91df5c10138a4aae/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_671f2f0c0250a9bd91df5c10138a4aae/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require
remote:        /tmp/build_671f2f0c0250a9bd91df5c10138a4aae/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
...
```

Really appreciate your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SEKRETS_KEY` environment variable on heroku having same value as what you configured in `.sekrets.key`

Visit https://github.com/ahoward/sekrets#key-lookup for more details